# How Do I make Chrome plug-ins un-disabled and uninstallable?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Let's say I have a plugin called Adblock. I don't want other users to disable or uninstall it. How Do I do that?

I hope to be able to do this through the registry, or Chrome hide settings.

What I currently think of is to disable the extension button, but this is not what I want, and it will affect the use of other plug -ins.